# Not sure if one or more

Tags: riddle, word

> With one I am just one, or more
>   With two I am no more, or one and more
>   With three I am just one, no more
>   With four I am just one, or more, or one of more I'm sure
>   With five I am just one, or more, and ultimately either or
>   With six I am just one, or more, and one or more before

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are

> **united**

With one I am just one, or more

> **u** $\rightarrow$ "you" can refer to one person or multiple people.

With two I am no more, or one and more

> **un** is a prefix that means a lack or reversal of something. It also means "a" in Spanish, which refers to a single thing or can refer to a larger set of things like "a group of people".  Additionally this represents the UN (United Nations) which is plural.

With three I am just one, no more

> **uni** is a prefix meaning consisting of one.

With four I am just one, or more, or one of more I'm sure

> **unit** is a single thing or a part consisting of many things or one of many constituent parts.

With five I am just one, or more, and ultimately either or

> **unite** is to combine multiple parts into one. The action can be done by one (“the company will unite with its competitors”) or many (“the companies will unite into one”).

With six I am just one, or more, and one or more before

> **united** - the same as the previous line, but since it is "before", it is past tense.

Comment: for the "with two" result, it makes sense when looking at its meaning in French

Comment: Oh yes, you got the original for the full 100% right! There's one more "group abbreviation" I tried to include with my edit for line 2.

Comment: Added.  I had that at first but changed my mind.  It's there now.

Comment: That's the one, almost forgot but the title is a hint too, for the difference between "things" and "people" for line 5 and 6.

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> 1 (binary one padded with zeros in front depending on length)

With one I am just one, or more

> 01 - with one 0 = 1 or more if we add more 1s at the end

With two I am no more, or one and more

> 001 still = 1 and more if we add more 1s like above

With three I am just one, no more

> 0001 = 1

With four I am just one, or more, or one of more I'm sure

> 00001 same as above

With five I am just one, or more, and ultimately either or

> 000001 same as above

With six I am just one, or more, and one or more before

> 0000001 same as above

Comment: Er...could you please explain how it works?

Comment: Because I'm pretty sure you have a good idea, but like my slow brain isn't catching up to the 3rd, 4th, or 5th lines...

Comment: I'm not home for the moment, I'll expand my answer when I get home, it's hard to elaborate on a cracked screen cellphone.

Comment: +1 from me for the answer (which makes it more..), I like your thinking but not the answer for sure, it is a *word* I'm looking for.

Comment: "One" is a word hehe ;)